# How to separate program into classes after making it in one tab

Tags: java, class, processing

I have created a simple game in processing using java language however I created the game all in one tab and I now need to put everything into its own class so it looks organized and is easier to read however although I have created classes before I am struggling to put my code into separate classes and getting them to work. Below is an example of one of my classes

```
int pixelsize = 5;   // size of pixels on screen
int gridsize  = pixelsize * 8 + 5;
Player player;
ArrayList enemies = new ArrayList();
ArrayList bullets = new ArrayList();
int direction = 1; // where the wave moves to 
boolean incy = false;

void setup() {
    background(0);
    fill(255);
    size(800, 800);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);

    player.draw();

    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
        Bullet bullet = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
        bullet.draw();
    }

void createEnemies() {
    for (int i = 0; i < width/gridsize/2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            enemies.add(new Enemy(i*gridsize, j*gridsize + 20 ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is already separated into classes. what are you talking about?

Comment: I'm assuming by "tabs" you mean files.  You really should just google "creating java classes".  I'm sure if you searched it before asking this question you would've gotten an answer.  If you're not sure how to do that, I don't think any answer given here is going to be of much use because it sounds like you lack the technical jargon to understand  said answers.

Comment: I think his question is about separating classes into different files for viewing each in its own tab in processing IDE ( https://processing.org/ ). I don't see why doing this manually should be hard considering the code is small, clean and contains around 4 classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Click this button:

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the **New Tab** option. Give your tab a name that matches the name of the class you want in that tab. I'll use `Ball`:

[image]

**Step 3:** Write the code for your class in that tab:

```
class Ball {

  float x;
  float y;

  void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void drawBall() {
    fill(ballColor);
    ellipse(x, y, 25, 25);
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** Write the code for the sketch in the first tab:

```
Ball ball = new Ball();

color ballColor = #00ff00;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ball.setPosition(mouseX, mouseY);
  ball.drawBall();
}
```

Notice that this sketch can use the class in the other tab, and the class can use functions or variables defined in the sketch tab.

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/environment/#Tabs).

Comment: @m.hussain Cut each class out of your original sketch and post it into its own tab.

Comment: @m.hussain I'm not sure what answer you're looking for. Maybe try posting the exact code you're trying to run (split up into tabs, not one huge code block) along with the exact text of any errors you're getting. You might want to do that in a separate question.

Comment: Ok, ill try doing that thanks. on your last comment you said to cut out my classes out of my original sketch and to put them into their own tabs. so you mean to create new classes and then put their information from the main sketch into their own classes right?

Also in my question how do i post separate bits of code to represent different classes.

Comment: Yes, you'd follow the steps just like in my answer. You might even start a new sketch and copy stuff from your existing sketch into the new sketch's tabs. And to post multiple tabs, just include multiple blocks of codes, each with the tab's name before it. You should have multiple code blocks, not one big one.

Comment: @m.hussain The thing that's confusing is your code is **already** separated into classes. You just need to put those classes into their own tabs. You haven't told us what errors you're getting, so it's hard to help you debug. That's why you might have better luck if you post a new question that contains code and screenshots that show exactly how you're separating it, as well as the full text of any errors you're getting.

Comment: @m.hussain StackOverflow comments aren't really built for questions and answers like that. I'd post new questions if I were you. You'll have more luck if you ry to come up with smaller examples and post your code as a [mcve] instead of posting your whole sketch, and include only one specific question per post.